# I am getting this error: Block is not a constructor in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, blockchain

I am new to Blockchain learning. I am following tutorial. I am getting this error. I am unable to resolve in VS code.

```
    const Block = require('./block');




describe('Block',()=> {
    const timestamp='a-date';
    const lastHash='foo-lasthash';
    const hash='foo-hash';
    const data=['foo-data','pdata'];
    const block= new Block({
        timestamp,
        lastHash,
        hash,
        data


    });

    it('has a timestamp,lastHash,hash, and data property',()=>{
      expect(block.timestamp).toEqual(timestamp); 
      expect(block.lastHash).toEqual(lastHash);  
      expect(block.hash).toEqual(hash);  
      expect(block.data).toEqual(data);   
    })

});
```

Here is the error message:

```
FAIL /block.test.js
 Block
  x encountered a declaration exception ( 18ms )
 • Block > encountered a declaration exception
  TypeError : Block is not a constructor
     91 const hash = ' foo - hash ' ;
     10 | const data = [ ' foo - data ' , ' pdata ' ] ;
              const block = new Block ( {
                          A
   > 11
     12 |
     13 |
     14 |
                  timestamp .
                  lastHash ,
                  hash ,
    at Suite . < anonymous > ( block . test.js : 11 : 18 )
     at Object . < anonymous > ( block.test.js : 6 : 1 )
Test Suites : 1 failed , 1 total
Tests : 1 failed , 1 total
Snapshots : 0 total
Time : 6.734s
Ran all test suites .
```

output is shown.. test is failed

[image: 1]

Comment: Don't post images to errors, post the actual error text directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `require` statement is failing. You are initializing a block object `const block= new Block` but `Block` is not defined.

since usually class modules file names starts with capital letter it might be './Block'

```
 const Block = require('./Block')
```

or your relative path is wrong. './block' means your test and `block` file are in the same directory. Make sure your relative path is correct.